# Passing a variable into Mapfile

Tags: mapserver, p-mapper

How can one pass a variable into a Mapfile using MapServer with p.mapper 
I would like to learn how generate maps dynamically  having different extent, layers, default settings, etc.. by varying a variable in just one Mapfile.

This variable could have different values, e.g. 
depending from user&password login.

Answer (score 4):

MapServer offers Runtime-Substitution that can help you define different values for the same mapfile configuration: http://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html